# Differentiate between two redirects in .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this **.htaccess**:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME}! -D
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME} .php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ category.php?slug=$1

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ game.php?slug=$1
```

I don't know how to differentiate the content that goes to category.php and the one that goes to game.php. Everything is shown in category.php. If I change the order everything would show in game.php

In the menu I pass the following link for categories for example:

```
<a href="action-games">Action Games</a>
```

And in **category.php** I collect it like this to compare it with the database slug field:

```
<?php
$category=$_GET['slug'];
$result = explode('/',$category);
$slug_c = $result[0];
?>
```

I have another project that I do something similar and the .htaccess is configured like this:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^colour/(.*)$  colour.php?name=$1
RewriteRule ^style/(.*)$  style.php?name=$1
RewriteRule ^article/(.*)$  article.php?name=$1
RewriteRule ^edit/(.*)$  edit.php?name=$1
```

What I want is for it to look like example.com/action-games. I don't want it to look like example.com/category/action-games

Comment: You need to differentiate when a request should go to one page vs. the other. Regex matches patterns. If you use the same regex obviously only one action can occur. e.g. on SO `questions/\d+` sends the question to a question template where as `questions/tagged/\w+` send it to a global thread page.

Comment: What I would like is for it to look like this: example.com/category1 and example.com/game1. The name of the category and the game directly at the root.

Comment: Try `RewriteRule ^(game|category)(\d+)$ $1.php?slug=$2` assuming `slug` should have the numerical value after the type of page it is.

Comment: In slug I am passing the name "category-one" or "game-one"

Comment: How/why are you going from numerical to text?

Comment: Because in the database I keep the slug of each game and category as text and check it by means of the slug, not the numerical ID.

Comment: You don't have an integer Id column? This is going to be a hinderous for you in the future. Think of how slow SO would be if they looked up questions by `differentiate-between-two-redirects-in-htaccess` instead of `60974709`. (My SO correlations are theoretical)

Answer (score 1):

This probably is what you are looking for, it considers "words" preceded by "category-" or "game-". So you may have to tweak it for you exact setup:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME}! -f
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME}! -d
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ $1.php [END]

RewriteRule ^/?category-(\w+)$ category.php?slug=$1 [END]
RewriteRule ^/?game-(\w+)$ game.php?slug=$1 [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I have edited the question to add more information on how I passed the variables.

Comment: Sorry, but you need to get more precise. You contradict yourself even in your attempts to clarify. In your question there _still_ is no pattern or example of the actual URLs you try to rewrite. Why not? In the comments to your questions you claim you use patterns like "category-one". In the update to your question you then suddenly reveal you look for a slash ("/") when parsing the "slug" parameter. Now what is actually true?

Comment: I am not an expert in explaining this, sorry. What counts is my question. There are terms that I don't know very well. I try to explain what I would like to do. Surely in my code there are some errors that I don't know, that's why I have come here. Perhaps this would be left over from the code: `$result = explode('/', $category);`

Comment: You seem to be offended, yet all I did is point out _why_ it is not possible to answer to your question. For that you are offended? Think again... I asked, why you do not specify a URL you want to redirect. But instead of doing that you change subject and talk about "being an expert" and "terms" instead of simply adding an actual URL. Why?

Comment: Hello, I'm not offended at all. Excuse me if it seemed. I was powerless not knowing how to explain my situation. In fact, your comments have helped me a lot to reach the solution. In my head I did not have the concept well ordered. My language is not English, so I have to translate what I mean. Maybe I didn't express myself well, but I'm not offended, but grateful.

Comment: But still you don't add actual URLs or change the claims in the question clearly contradicting your solution. Interesting. Oh, and by the way, very few here are native English speakers. I am not. Never mind, you express yourself very well on a linguistic level. As said: have fun!

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved. What I have done is put part of the URL that I wanted to display as a prefix:

```
RewriteRule ^games-of-([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/?$ category.php?slug=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ game.php?slug=$1
```

This way there is no prefix followed by "/" but "-" so it seems like it is directly a root dependent URL.

Comment: This _again_ contradicts what you claimed before. Impressive... Anyway, glad you found a solution that works for you! Have fun!